# AJAX not calling php file from JS?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, html

### The Problem:

Hello, I made sure that my PHP file is working, but unfortunately my ajax code is not. I placed the ajax inside a javascript function to call the file when needed, but when the function is executed nothing happens.

---

### The Code:

***Here is my JS Code:***

```
function countdownEnded() {
    //make serverscreen dissapear
        document.getElementById('serverScreenWrapper').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('serverScreenWrapper').style.opacity = '0';
        document.getElementById("cashOutNumTwo").style.right = '150%';
        document.getElementById("cashOutNumOne").style.right = '150%';
//start Timer
        setInterval(gameTimer.update, 1000);
//make player move again
        socket.emit('4');
        socket.emit('6');
//make game appear
        document.getElementById('gameAreaWrapper').style.opacity = 1;
//play sound
        document.getElementById('spawn_cell').play();
//cut 5 cents from account - php function
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'http://cashballz.net/game/5game/subtract5.php',
        data: { },
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data);
        }
    });
}
```

***My HTML:***

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
```

***And even my PHP:***

```
<?php
session_start();

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "myName";
$password = "myPass*";
$dbname = "myDBname";
$cash_amount = $_SESSION['cash_amount'];

// Create connection

$userid = $_SESSION['id'];

// You must enter the user's id here. /\

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

// Fetch the existing value of the cash_amount against that particular user here. You can use the SELECT cash_amount from users where userid = $userid

$_SESSION['cash_amount'] -= 0.05;

$sql = "UPDATE users SET cash_amount = cash_amount - 0.05 WHERE id = ?";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param('s', $userid);
$result = $stmt->execute();


if($result)
{
   echo "5 cents have been subtracted!";
}
else
{
   echo mysqli_error($conn);
   session_start();
   session_unset();
   session_destroy();
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

---

### Conclusion:

I don't understand why my file isn't being called.

I have JQuery and i researched quite a bit on AJAX and looked at other similiar questions on this site.

I went to the file link and it works perfectly so i am pretty sure this is a javascript error.

I am great at JS, but a beginner to PHP and JQuery.

Thanks for all your help.

Comment: Out of curiosity, is the Ajax code also being hosted on ‘cashballz.net’ ? Might be a cross origin problem if that’s the case. Try adding an error event handler in your Ajax call and print the results to your console and see if that’s being called.

Comment: Have you done your due diligence first by checking the developer console in your browser for possible errors? Does the `countdownEnded` actually fire off to start with (not shown here how that is called)? Added any debugging `console.log('such n such');` in the javascript to watch events and the like?

Comment: @IncredibleHat Of course I have, the countdownEnded is firing off for sure because it does many other things than control the AJAX, and there are no bugs being shown.

Comment: @TomaszFoster Everything is being hosted on my dedicated server, i didn't even know it was possible to host files from different sources

Comment: I had to ask. Only to make sure there were no errors displayed (which many people don't even realize exist, you'd be surprised). If there are no errors, and there is no hit in the network tab either... its an unknown. Either js will error about something not working, or .ajax would have hit something. But since you say nothing is happening in either case... boggling.

Comment: Yeah i am always confused when this happens, let me move stuff around and see if it can get to give me an error, maybe i'm blocking it in some way

Comment: If its a cross-domain issue, are you hitting the initial page from the same domain of `http://cashballz.net/`... or maybe you hit it from `http://www.cashballz.net/` ? Could be a simple fix, or a complex one ;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173854/discussion-between-patrick-and-incrediblehat).

Comment: looks like cross domain issue

Answer (score 0):

Try modifying your ajax call to include an error handlers. As an example:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'http://cashballz.net/game/5game/subtract5.php',
    data: { },
    success: function (data) {
        alert(data);
    },
    error: function(data) {
        alert(data);
    }
```

Comment: It was a cross domain issue but I am still struggling with it

Answer (score 0):

PHP: 
`header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');` to allow cross domain access.

Comment: This does fix it, but introduces a very large security issue. Adding the link says the value is not liable, so i don't know what link to use instead of the * you used.

Comment: header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: YOUR DOMAIN'); ?

Comment: Yeah but when i do this, it works, and it echos success, but the database is not being updated... When i open the link in my browser, then it works, which is super confusing.

Comment: $_SESSION['id'] is not null ?